# Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Help, I have been trying to run a discord bot. The bot works fine on my computer. However when I upload it to my server to run it. It gives me this error.

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './locationPlaces.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Commands/nextPlace.js:3:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

locationPlaces.json is a file im reading from. Which is in the correct place. So I think this might be a problem with node. this is the line of code its refering to in the error

`const locationPlaces = require("./locationPlaces.json")`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the JSON File being refered too

```
{    
    "Terminal": {       
        "places": [ "Bathrooms", "Airport-Bus-Stop", "Help-Desk"],
        "description": "You arrive inside the south terminal of Bandaranaike International Airport. People are rushing about everywhere trying to catch their flight. You see a helpdesk, some bathrooms, and an exit to a bus stop",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/DGh5vkw.jpg"
    },
    "Help-Desk": {       
        "places": [ "Bathrooms", "Airport-Bus-Stop", "Terminal"],
        "description": "You make your way over to the help desk, asking the woman for information on Yala National Park. She briefly says, Yala is amazing, many things are hidden within its safari!, make sure you listen to the announcements, they can be game changing!",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/oXM4XW7.jpg"
    },
    "Bathrooms": {       
        "places": [ "Airport-Bus-Stop", "Help-Desk", "Terminal", "Stall"],
        "description": "The bathroom isnt anything special, you seem someone brushing their teeth in the sink",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/sWppInG.jpg"
    },
    "Airport-Bus-Stop": {       
        "places": [ "Terminal", "Help-Desk", "Bathrooms", "Park-A-Bus","Visitor-Park-Bus"],
        "description": "You walk out of the airport to the bus station. You check the departures, there is one for Yala Park Entrance A, Yala Park C & Yala Visitor Park",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/0Vz7rmZ.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: the error maybe in the export of the file it self , can you show the export part in this file "locationPlaces.json"

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean. The JSON File?

Comment: yes "locationPlaces.json"

Comment: Alright, edited the post to show it.

Comment: check your node version to make sure that feature is supported

Comment: I'm using node v8.10.0 From what I know it should still be supported

Comment: the error is just saying it can't find the file, check if everything is uploaded in the server correctly. And just in case if the nodejs version is the same as your pc.